# How can you render out just the audio from a video in VSE?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, video-sequence-editor, file-format

Basically all I need to do is render out the track (the top most bar that appears when you drop a video in VSE). I am pretty new to Blender's VSE and I haven't been able to find anything about what I am looking for on the forum, so I thought I would ask for help here.

I really appreciate all ideas and info!

Thanks!

Comment: There is a render Audio button next to the render Animation button.

Comment: I tried that but it just renders it out and you cant understand it because it is so crunchy-sounding...

Answer (score 1):

Blender isn't a good choice if you are only outputting audio, blender will still render an image for each frame. You can delete all objects in the scene and choose blender render or set samples to one with cycles and use a small image size (50x50) to cut the render time.

If you are only extracting the audio from a file, you would be better off not using blender, using ffmpeg in a terminal it is much quicker to copy the audio track from a video without any conversion.

```
ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -acodec copy audioonly.mp3
```

You may also want to use [audactity](https://www.guidingtech.com/12836/extract-audio-from-video-audacity/) to open the video file and save out the audio.

If you do want to use blender, in the output settings, select ffmpeg video. For container select one that supports multiple codecs, such as mpeg-4 and then for video codec choose No Video (2.7x this shows as None).

[image: no video settings]

Comment: What about the "mixdown" option? It only render the audio, right?

Comment: @leander actually in 2.80 that does work. For me in 2.79 it only outputs bad noise. I had thought it only worked with output from [speaker objects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/audio/speaker.html).

Comment: I've used it countless times in 2.79. Check the sampling quality options. I'm not on a computer right now.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah I definitely had to do a low of tweaking and such but I thin k I got it to work.